# Adding databing to a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, object, data-binding, binding, datagrid

I have a simple datastructure following:

In the model I have

```
    public class Receipt
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Store { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

I've made two of these objects and I am trying to bind them to a datagrid. I've filled in the properties of the two receipts and added them to the dataGridRows but they don't show up in my DataGrid.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    makeReceipts()
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Receipt> dataGridRows = new ObservableCollection<Receipt>();

    public Receipt receipt1 = new Receipt();
    public Receipt receipt2 = new Receipt();

    public void makeReceipts()
    {
    receipt1.Id = 1;
    receipt1.Price = 10;
    receipt1.Store = "Brugsen";
    receipt1.Date = DateTime.Today;

    receipt2.Id = 2;
    receipt2.Price = 15;
    receipt2.Store = "Netto";
    receipt2.Date = DateTime.Today;

    dataGridRows.Add(receipt1);
    dataGridRows.Add(receipt2);
    }
```

And in the xaml of the MainWindow where I want my datagrid to display the receipts I have:

```
    <DataGrid Name="ReceiptGrid" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=dataGridRows}" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is this `public ObservableCollection<Receipt> dataGridRows` defined?

Comment: in the MainWindow.xaml.cs, just outside of the method I used to declare the two objects properties..

Answer (score 0):

first you can just bind to **public properties**. 
so if you want to use binding you have at least do:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Receipt> dataGridRows {get;set;}
```

second you have to do two steps:

1. set the right datacontext
2. set the right binding expression(Path)

assume that the datacontext for yyour grid is an object with the property dataGridRows, your binding should look like this

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dataGridRows}" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think your problem is you have to write

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=dataGridRows}"
```

and not

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source=dataGridRows}"
```

source is to specify another control in xaml file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can bind only public properites so you need to change definition of `dataGridRows` to something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Receipt> dataGridRows { get; set; }
```

then you don't bind it as a `Source` but as a `Path`, however since your `dataGridRows` is defined in `MainWindow` you need to specify `Source` as your `MainWindow` otherwise it will look in default `DataContext` which is not set in your case

```
<DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=dataGridRows}" />
```

this tells `Binding` to find `Window` and look for a `dataGridRows` property there.
**EDIT:**
Normally you don't put data into view. I suggest you read more about MVVM design pattern but basically the idea is that you have your ViewModel where you put in you whole application logic, unaware of interface, and then on top you have your view to interact with user but in ViewModel you don't operate on controls.
What you should do is create your view-model class with `dataGridRows` property and assign it through [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of `Window` for example. Each `FrameworkElement` has it and when you don't specify [`Binging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) source (`Source`, `RelativeSource`, `ElementName`) it will try to resolve `Binding.Path` in current `DataContext`. If current control does not have it specified then if will go to parent in visual tree and so on.

Comment: If I where to have my dataGridRows somewhere else, what would be a good location? Should I define it in the Receipt model itself?

Comment: @Zeliax, I've updated my answer with short explanation of what you should do

Comment: Thanks. That made it a little more understandable. So basicly I should create some controls (classes in ViewModel) to handle all the Models. An example could be ReceiptViewModel which creates instances of the receipt and handles the data?

`AddReceipt` and stuff alike should be in the ReceiptViewModel or how is it?

Comment: @Zeliax: yes, that is exactly how it should work. Basically ViewModel is UI independent application which uses generic classes from your Model (like DB access) and View binds to it to allow interaction. If you just start with WPF then it will be easiest to start with MVVM. There are ready frameworks like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which make it much easier. In WPF you have to do very little interaction with controls UI basically creates itself through templates and bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm currently working on improving my MVVM coding skills, which seems a little bit tricky, but luckily the tutorials on the internet for MVVM is way better than for just simple databindings ;)